# Redirecting a user back to the page they where viewing after login

Tags: php

Okay, so say for an example the user is visiting:

```
mysite.com/user/profile/demo,
```

and they perform an action to follow said user and go to:

```
mysite.com/user/follow/demo,
```

and they have to be logged in, so it redirects them to the login form, and they try to login once, but it fails, and then they successfully login the seconds time, if I use:

```
history.go(-1)
```

That'll go back to the login page 'cause they've failed login once. What is a way around this? Using a

```
?referrer=user/profile/demo then if that's set go back to that page?
```

I'm open to ideas, so that'll be cool if you gave me some.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `mysite.com/user/follow/demo`, before you redirect to the login page, you could save the current url in the session. Then, once they've successfully logged in, you can check for the existence of this session variable and redirect to it.

Example:

`mysite.com/user/follow/demo`

```
<?php
session_start();
if (not logged in) {
  $_SESSION['redirect_after_login'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
  header('Location: /login');
  exit;
}
...
```

`mysite.com/login`

```
<?php
session_start();
...
login code
...
if (user has logged in) {
  if (isset($_SESSION['redirect_after_login'])) {
    $url = $_SESSION['redirect_after_login'];
    unset($_SESSION['redirect_after_login']);
    header('Location: ' . $url);
    exit;
  }
}
```

Note: untested pseudo code

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you store the location to redirect to in say `GET` as using history.go will, naturally, go back in history and not update the login button etc.

When the user has logged in, set `header('Location: ' . $_GET["r"]);` to redirect the user back.